# How model field will be field automatically with the user ids

Tags: django, model

I am creating a payment/paid-subscription for my django project. I decided to create a separate payment app and connect it to my django project. In below, you see the model for payment which I expect to have user ids with their payment status(for now just want to start with `default=False`):

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'payment'
```

1. I created this, but in the database table, I see the `user_id` and
   `paid` are empty, while I have already a lot of users signed up. How
   to bring those ids here, with a default false paid?
2. And what should I do to say django that after each new sign up fill
   this model as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1 - Updating existing users to have a Payment

Django won't automatically do this for you, you can go into the shell, and create `Payment` instances for each user:

Enter the shell (`python manage.py shell`)

```
from myapp.models import Payment

users = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    Payment.objects.create(user=user, paid=False)
```

If you want to be more effecient you could do something like this:

```
payments = [Payment(user=user, paid=False) for user in User.objects.all()]
Payment.objects.bulk_create(payments)
```

If this is an app that you have already deployed somewhere else you should create a data-migration to do this for you:

```
from django.db import migrations

def create_payments(apps, schema_editor):
    Payment = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Payment')
    User = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'User')
    payments = [Payment(user=user, paid=False) for user in User.objects.all()]
    Payment.objects.bulk_create(payments)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_payments),
    ]
```

#### Part 2 - Creating Payments on every new sign-up

This will depend alot on how you are doing your sign-ups, so its difficult to give an exact answer. But wherever your new user object is created you just want to add something like:

```
Payment.objects.create(user=user, paid=False)
```

If you have a form that is handling user sign-ups maybe do it in the `save` method of that form. If you're using something like django rest framework, it would go in whatever view creates the `User`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already created another app within which I defined a `Profile` app and inside of this folder defined a module named `signals` that partially does savings. However I didn't get what you said, Is my Profile app enough for such a model and I need to erase `Payment` app?

Comment: @elisaFo Sorry, when I read your question, I must have misread `Payment` for `Profile`. I have edited my answer accordingly. Everywhere I had put `Profile` is not `Payment`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I also didn't see question 2 in your original question. I'll update to answer that too.